# Display message without alert and textarea on click

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json

I have a json id for servlet reference and there is a message in this json id which I need to print on the webpage.
It works with textarea tag and alert, but I need to display the message in style (decorative,animate)
How can I do it?

Here is the ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/hello3",
    type:"GET",
    data:"currentId=" +currentId ,
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(data,status){
    $('#json').val(" The deleted row is "+data.currentId)

}
});
});
});
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div>
    <textarea id="json" rows="10" cols="50" disabled></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: in style?  got an example?

Comment: Based on the question, It appears that the OP is asking about CSS? You can "pre-style" the div#json{style:style}, so that when it gets added to the DOM, the browser knows how to render it. It is also possible that the OP is asking about styling text _within_ a textarea, in which case, you can simply apply the same CSS rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**[DEMO]**](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/LmvCX/1/)

Try this

```
$('#json').hide();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/hello3",
            type: "GET",
            data: "currentId=" + currentId,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data, status) {
                $('#json').text(" The deleted row is " + data.currentId).slideDown();

            }
        });
    });
```

Hope this helps,Thank you